# Adding a list to the end of another list

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a piece of code in which I need to add a list to another list.

```
fun a(x:Int):List<List<Int>>{
  var a = 1.rangeTo(x);
  var b: List<List<Int>> = emptyList();
  for (i in a){
    var num1 = if(i<=3) i else 4;
    var list_a= 0.rangeTo(num1 - 1);
    b.add(list_a);
  }
  return b
}
```

I problem is `b.add(list_a)` is giving `error(unresolved reference)`.

In this function if I input `println(a(2))`
The output should be `[[0],[0,1]]`
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the `unresolved reference` for `b.add()` is because you have **initialized `b` as a `List` instead of `MutableList`**.

Please note that once initialized, **you can add elements to a `MutableList` but not a `List`** in Kotlin. Hence change your initialization of `b` as `var b: MutableList<List<Int>> = mutableListOf()`

```
fun a(x: Int): List<List<Int>> {
    var a = 1.rangeTo(x)
    var b: MutableList<List<Int>> = mutableListOf()
    for (i in a) {
        var num1 = if (i <= 3) i else 4
        var list_a = 0.rangeTo(num1 - 1).toList()
        b.add(list_a)
    }
    return b
}
```

Refactoring it a bit further, you can use `1..x` for the range in the `for` loop and `(0 until num1)` instead of `0.rangeTo(num1 - 1)` as below

```
fun a(x: Int): List<List<Int>> {
    val listB: MutableList<List<Int>> = mutableListOf()
    for (i in 1..x) {
        val num1 = if (i <= 3) i else 4
        val listA = (0 until num1).toList()
        listB.add(listA)
    }
    return listB
}
```